# How do I prevent Keras from always predicting the underlying distribution of my data?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, data-science

I am training a Deep CNN on a very unbalanced data set for a binary classification problem. I have 90% 0's and 10% 1's. To penalize the misclassification of 1, I am using a class_weight that was determined by sklearn's compute_class_weight(). In the validation tuple passed to the fit_generator(), I am using a sample_weight that was computed by sklearn's compute_sample_weight().

The network seems to be learning fine but the validation accuracy continues to be 90% or 10% after every epoch. How can I solve this data unbalance issue in Keras considering the steps I have already taken to overcome it?

Picture of fit_generator: [fit_generator()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmyqZ.png)

Picture of log outputs: [log outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7FrJ.png)

Comment: How many cases do you have in validation?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I have 1000 1's and 9000 0's. I am actually doing 0 vs all classification on CIFAR-10.

Answer (score 0):

It's ver y strange that your val_accuracy jumps from 0.9 to 0.1 and back. Do you have right learning rate? Try to lower it even more.

And my advice: use f1 metric also.

How did you split the data - train set classes have the same rate in test set?

Comment: Thanks for the response. What do you mean by "train set classes have the same rate in test set?"

Comment: Do you have the same classes balance in test and train sets: 90/10 in train and 90/10 in test?

Comment: I have 5000 1's and 45000 0's in my train set and 1000 1's and 9000 0's in my test set. @avchauzov

Comment: Seems good. Learning rate is lower than default?

And please share train and test learning curves.